# Set Default Zoom Level in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How do I get the default zoom to 75% on a worksheet? I can set it but when I do page  preview then back to the normal sheet it goes back to 100%. I've added a screen shot so you can see what I mean. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Setting the Default Print Preview Zoom Factor](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T000494_Setting_the_Default_Print_Preview_Zoom_Factor.html) :

> The short answer is that it isn't
>   possible. Why? Because the hard-wired
>   starting point for Print Preview is to
>   use a "Whole Page" zoom factor. This
>   is because Print Preview is designed
>   to let you see what the page will look
>   like when printed, not necessarily to
>   read what is on that page. There is no
>   way to change this default zoom factor
>   setting in Print Preview itself.
>
> There are workarounds, however. The
>   "Whole Page" zoom factor can vary in
>   size, depending on the size of the
>   actual page you are displaying and
>   depending on the size of the program
>   window you are using to display Word.
>   Thus, if you maximize the program
>   window, you end up with more space in
>   which to display the page in Print
>   Preview.
>
> The other possible workaround is to
>   create a macro that will display Print
>   Preview for you. The macro could be
>   assigned to a shortcut key or a
>   toolbar button (the Quick Access
>   toolbar in Word 2007) for easy use.
>   Here's an example of a macro that will
>   invoke Print Preview and then set the
>   zoom factor to 50%.
>
> ```
> Sub MyPrintPrev()
>     With ActiveWindow.View
>         .Type = wdPrintPreview
>         .Zoom.Percentage = 50
>     End With
> End Sub
> ```